# Entity Framework using Contains method as non-unicode

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to search a column value using Entity Framework Linq to entities method and i want to search text in column as non-unicode

That's why i'm using like this.

```
var text = "test";
var members = context.Members.Where(c => DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(c.Name).Contains(text)).ToList();
```

It throws exception something like " the argument should be string variable or literal."

How can i achieve that. I need to use Contains without unicode characters.

I mean when i search "Şheep" or "Sheep" i should find the row with column value "Sheep"

Also  when i search "Şheep" or "Sheep" i should find the row with column value "Şheep"

Name column is NVARCHAR in database. I'm trying to implement a search function. In that function when user searchs "şheepü", the rows with column value "sheepu", "şheepü", "şheepu" or "sheepü" should be found, and also if user searchs "sheepu" rows with column value "sheepu", "şheepü", "şheepu" or "sheepü" should be found,

Comment: Are you using a full text index? If not, have you thought about using one? Converting the source value from unicode like this will not give you the result you expect.

Comment: im not using any index, 

Name column is NVARCHAR in database. I'm trying to implement a search function. In that function when user searchs "şheepü", the rows with column value "sheepu", "şheepü", "şheepu" or "sheepü" should be found, and also if user searchs "sheepu" rows with column value "sheepu", "şheepü", "şheepu" or "sheepü" should be found,

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You have to search for all possible values. You can also replace all characters that have multiple representations with `_` and finish the selection with an in-memory search.